# How can I import fonts from node_modules with webpack and postcss/cssnext

Tags: fonts, webpack, node-modules, postcss, cssnext

I'm need to use font-awesome.
PostCSS tries to find font in source directory but not in node_modules/font-awesome/fonts

Error text:

```
Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0' in 'F:\OpenServer\domains\polymer-postcss\src'
```

Import:

```
@import "font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css";
```

webpack.config.js:

```
var cssPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
    entry:      {app: './src/app.js'},
    output: {
        path:       './dist',
        filename:   '[name].js',
        publicPath: '/dist/',

    },
    plugins: [new cssPlugin({filename: '[name].css'}),],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: cssPlugin.extract({
                    use: 'css-loader?importLoaders=1&sourceMap!postcss-loader?sourceMap',
                }),
            },
            {   
                test: /\.(svg|png|gif|jpe?g|woff|woff2|eot|ttf)$/i,
                use: "url-loader?limit=10000&name=[path][name].[ext]?[hash]"
            },
        ],
    },
}
```

postcss.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: {
        'postcss-import': {},
        'postcss-cssnext': {
            browsers: ['last 2 versions', '> 20%'],
        },
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This PostCSS module really solved my problem

https://github.com/devex-web-frontend/postcss-assets-rebase

Answer (score -2):

You can use `fa-font-path` to change where `font-awesome` looks for the fonts. In your CSS you can do it like this:

```
@fa-font-path: "font-awesome/fonts";
@import "font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css";
```

Although I've usually only seen it in `.scss` by setting the `$fa-font-path` variable. The `postcss-import` will complain that import statements need to come first, but at least it still works.

You can also use the `@import` syntax in CSS without the `postcss-import`, the `css-loader` supports it. The only difference is that you need to start your paths with a `~` to indicate that it should be resolved as a `node_module`, because otherwise it's interpreted as a relative path (as shown in the [`css-loader` Readme](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#options)). Without the `postcss-import`, the following works and does not produce a warning:

```
@fa-font-path: "font-awesome/fonts";
@import "~font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css";
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this not works.

My task is to change SCSS to cssnext and not use SCSS anymore.
Standard syntax is better))
Simultaneously I need to continue using libraries from node_modules that uses fonts, images, etc.

So, for now the best answer is found by me, Maybe you interested in it too:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/43299680/1638298